# Get sublime text 2 (sublimecodeintel) to parse mason

Tags: text-editors, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-2

So Sublime Text 2 seems to getting a lot of love lately. I am using the [Sublime Code intel plugin](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel), for auto completion. The problem is, it does not recognize .mi files as MASON files. I looked into the lexer and it does have the keywords in place. How do I force it to be parsed as MASON?

Running "Set Syntax: " on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, does not show a MASON option.

Comment: i doubt it has anything to do with CTRL+SHIFT+P, the syntax changer is something from Sublime Text itself, the plugin works with his own list of supported languages, however I'm looking for a guide on how it works with Javascript, so I am awaiting an answer on your post, to see if I can do a similar trick to make it work with Javascript :)